# interpolation inequality in Vlasov-Poisson equation

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading "Propagation of moments and regularity for the 3-dimensional Vlasov-Poisson system, by P.L. Lions 1 and B. Perthame"

[image]

where $\rho(t,x)=\int f(t,x,v)dv.$

I don't know how to apply interpolation inequality to above. Is this "interpolation inequality" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality ?

And I'm also hard to understand (14). Someone help me plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, this is clearly not the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality. Interpolation inequalities are usually inequalities of the form $\|f\|_{Z} ≤ \|f\|_{X}^{\theta}\|f\|_{Z}^{1-\theta}$. There are a lot of them. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space
2. What did you try?
3. *Hints:*

   - To get the first inequality, just write $\rho = ∫_0^R f\,\mathrm d v + ∫_R^\infty f\,\mathrm d v$.
   - Remark that the r.h.s. of the first inequality is of the form $g(R) = a R^{-k} + b R^3$. This function as a minimum on $\mathbb R_+$ (I let you find why). To get (14), just take the $R$ that minimizes $g(R)$ (so the $R$ such that $g'(R)=0$, since the minimum is unique and $g$ is $C^1$).

Comment: I'm sorry I checked late, thank u very much